# Is it possible to create a product box that I can add/remove the surface art from without changing the 3D model?

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing

I am a complete noob and am just using blender for my first time this week. I am hoping to create a 3D model of a pack of rolling papers with custom art on it. I have the dieline created for the project. I was wondering if I could create a 3d model of the rolling papers but be able to change the dieline/images without having to create the 3 model from scratch everytime? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You will always be able to change the image as long as you use an image texture node for the base color.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm guessing the best way to do this is create a 3d model by using the dieline as the base/blueprint? Is there a certain function in Blender that I could use to accomplish this? Just not sure where to start.

Comment: @Tyler  you will create the base object and then UV Unwrap the object.  Then you can use that UV texture coordinate data to assign any image texture to the mesh.

Comment: There are many UV Unwrapping tutorial videos on the famous website that has a name that rhymes with noonoob.  Tutorials might be good for anyone.